# Generic half func in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write generic half function for all numeric types:

```
func half<T where T: FloatingPointType>(value: T) -> T
{
    return value * 0.5
}
```

And I see this error:

> No '*' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'T'

Is it possible to write generic function in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write *"all numeric types"*, but based on the `0.5` multiplication this answer is based on the assumption that you refer to the commonly use floating point types (`Double`, `Float`, `CGFloat`).

You could create a custom protocol that blueprints the `*` function (for multiplying to values of `Self`) as well as an initializer by `FloatLiteralType`, and conform `Double`, `Float` and `CGFloat` to this protocol. The `*` function as well as the initializer are already implemented for these three types, so the conformance is simply explicitly telling the compiler that these types indeed conform to your custom protocol.

E.g.

```
protocol MyFloatingPointTypes {
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    init(_: FloatLiteralType)
}

extension Double : MyFloatingPointTypes {}
extension Float : MyFloatingPointTypes {}
extension CGFloat : MyFloatingPointTypes {}

func half<T: MyFloatingPointTypes>(value: T) -> T {
    return value * T(0.5)
}

/* example usage */
var dVal: Double = 10.5
var fVal: Float = 10.5
var cfVal: CGFloat = 10.5

dVal = half(dVal)
fVal = half(fVal)
cfVal = half(cfVal)

print(dVal, fVal, cfVal) // 5.25 5.25 5.25
```

#### Alternative: compound protocol constraint, using `FloatLiteralConvertible`

As @Hamish writes in his comments below, rather than blueprinting the initializer by `Double` (`init(_: FloatLiteralType)` in `MyFloatingPointTypes`, a better approach is to instead add an additional type constraint to the generic `half(...)` function, constraining the generic (in addition to `MyFloatingPointTypes`) to `FloatLiteralConvertible`:

```
// lets rename this protocol here, since it no longer has any direct association with floats
protocol Multiplicable {
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Double : Multiplicable {}
extension Float : Multiplicable {}
extension CGFloat : Multiplicable {}

func half<T: protocol<Multiplicable, FloatLiteralConvertible>>(value: T) -> T {
    return value * 0.5
}

/* example usage */
// ... same as above
```

#### Another (more general) alternative: compound protocol constraint, using `IntegerLiteralConvertible`

Or, if you want you `half` function to extend its generic "coverage" also to integer types (as also pointed out by @Hamish, thanks!) you could use the same compound protocol constraint method as above, but against `IntegerLiteralConvertible`:

```
protocol Divisable {
    func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Double : Divisable {}
extension Float : Divisable {}
extension CGFloat : Divisable {}
extension Int: Divisable {}

func half<T: protocol<Divisable, IntegerLiteralConvertible>>(value: T) -> T {
    return value / 2
}

/* example usage */
var dVal: Double = 10.5
var fVal: Float = 10.5
var cfVal: CGFloat = 10.5
var iVal: Int = 11

dVal = half(dVal)
fVal = half(fVal)
cfVal = half(cfVal)
iVal = half(iVal) // truncates decimal part

print(dVal, fVal, cfVal, iVal) // 5.25 5.25 5.25 5
```

Comment: Thanks, it works even with Swift 2.2 and even with Int if rewrite to "value / T(2)".

Comment: @ChikabuZ Happy to help. Note, however, that there are numerous integer types (`Int8`, `UInt8`, `Int16`, ...), so while the method above is somewhat feasibly if you limit yourself to the common floating point types, it becomes messy if you were to include all integer types. So if you want a similar function also for integer types, it's probably better to make a separate generic function type constrained to Swift native protocol [`IntegerType`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/IntegerType), e.g. `func half<T: IntegerType>(value: T) -> T { return value / 2 }`.

Comment: This is the solution that I had in mind (+1) – although I would use the `FloatLiteralConvertible` (`ExpressibleByFloatLiteral` in Swift 3) protocol as a requirement, rather than an initialiser that takes a `Double` (`FloatLiteralType` is just a typealias) – that way you can simply express the arithmetic as `return value * 0.5`. You could also use `IntegerLiteralConvertible` to work with integer literals (e.g `value / 2`). I also think you meant to add some explicit type annotations for your example usage ;)

Comment: @Hamish All good points, thanks, included in answer! Although done in a rush, so I'll look over this later, gotta run now. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Not in Swift 2.2. `FloatingPointType` is not a very powerful type. In Swift 3 this is possible if you limit yourself to `BinaryFloatingPoint` (which covers most of the floating point types you're probably thinking of, particularly `Float` and `Double`).

```
func half<T where T: BinaryFloatingPoint>(_ value: T) -> T {
    return value * 0.5
}
```

In the most general case of a custom `FloatingPointType` in Swift 2.2, the system may not have any way to convert this into a `Double` multiplication and then convert that back into your arbitrary `FloatingPointType`. The `BinaryFloatingPoint` protocol adds `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral` which means that `0.5` can be converted to your arbitrary type.

It's important to keep in mind that the `0.5` in this above code is of type `T`. It is not a `Double`. The following code still would not work:

```
func half<T where T: BinaryFloatingPoint>(_ value: T) -> T {
    let oneHalf = 0.5
    return value * oneHalf 
   // error: binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'Double'
}
```

You cannot multiply two arbitrary floating point numbers. Swift intentionally avoids a lot of automatic type coercion that was a source of subtle bugs in C. In the general case of a custom `FloatingPoint`, it is not possible to say that one type is "more accurate" than the other. They may have different accuracy over different ranges. And of course you could create a `FloatingPoint` that is much larger than a double. So there's no obvious "just promote everything to double" rule that you could use.